# Finding the real solutions to $16^{x^{2} + y } + 16^{y^{2}+ x} = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have , $16^{x^{2} + y } + 16^{y^{2}+ x} = 1$ , then we have to find all the real values of $x$ and $y$.I tried this question  but i am not able to proceed because I am not able to simplify this expression to an extent that it could be solved.

Comment: It is easy to see that $x$ and $y$ could not be positive, I think. But real numbers, that's hard?

Comment: One place to start looking is where $x = y$. Then you have
$$
16^{x^2 + x} = \frac{1}{2} \implies x^2 + x = -\frac{1}{4}
$$
so $x = y = -\frac{1}{2}$ is _one_ solution (at least now we know that solutions exist). Also, we can easily see that both $x^2 + y$ and $y^2 + x$ must be negative. This limits the search a lot (they're both between $-1$ and $0$).

Comment: $16^{x(x-1)}+16^{y(y-1)}=16^{-(x+y)}$

Comment: $16^{x^2+y}+16^{x+y^2} = 16^{x^2+y^2}(16^{y-y^2}+16^{x-x^2})$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$x^2 + y^2 + x + y = (x + 1/2)^2 + (y + 1/2)^2 - 1/2 \geq -1/2$ and equality occurs only when $x = y = - 1/2$.

Using AM-GM inequality $16^{x^2 + y} + 16^{y^2 + x} \geq 2\cdot\sqrt{16^{x^2+y^2+x+y}} \geq 2\cdot16^{-1/4} = 1$ and equality occurs only when $x=y=-1/2$

Comment: Wow. beautiful method :)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\mbox{Let's}\quad 4^{x^{2} + y} = \cos\pars{\theta}\,,\quad
4^{y^{2} + x} = \sin\pars{\theta}\qquad\mbox{with}\qquad \theta\ \in\ \pars{0,{\pi \over 2}}
$$

> $$
> x^{2} + y ={\ln\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}} \over 2\ln\pars{2}}\,,\qquad
> y^{2} + x ={\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}} \over 2\ln\pars{2}}
> $$

$$
\bracks{{\ln\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}} \over 2\ln\pars{2}} - x^{2}}^{2} + x ={\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}} \over 2\ln\pars{2}}
$$

> $$
> x^{4} - {\ln\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}} \over \ln\pars{2}}\,x^{2} + x
> +
> \bracks{{\ln^{2}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}} \over 4\ln^{2}\pars{2}}
> - {\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}} \over 2\ln\pars{2}}} = 0\,,\qquad
> \theta\ \in\ \pars{0,{\pi \over 2}}
> $$
>   which express $x$ ( parametrically ) as a function of $\theta$.

Comment: So how do you find all solutions using that monster function?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the original problem ,  but it is related to a procedure suggested by Arthur. It looks like we can always find real number solutions $(x , y)$ for $A \ge 1$

$$ 16^{x^2 + y} + 16^{y^2 + x} = A $$

$x^2 + y = y^2 + x = \dfrac{ln{(\frac{A}{2})}}{ln{16}}$